# Double integral of modulus of difference reference

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for some references about integrals of the form

$$ \int_\Omega \int_\Omega |f(x) - f(y)| dx dy.$$

I've only seen something like this for the definition of fractional Sobolev spaces, but I would like to know something about "integer" Sobolev spaces and more importantly without anything at the denominator. Any reference?

Comment: What is the context of your question? What property would you like to get? This does not seems a very interesting quantity, it is infinite if the domain is not of finite measure, and bounded by the $L^1$ norm else. Your property is $0$ for constant functions, so it is just a seminorm. If you want to make it a norm you can add the $L^1$ norm, but then the sum is equivalent to the $L^1$ norm  ... This kind of quantity is also often an intermediate quantity in the proof of Poincaré-like inequalities

Comment: @LL3.14 the fact is that $\Omega$ should have really small diameter, so I was wondering if there is some estimate depending on it. Let's say that $\Omega$ is a ball of diameter $\varepsilon$. If $f$ is smooth, we should have an upper bound of $\varepsilon^{2n+1}$, while if $f$ is $L^\infty$ we have $\varepsilon ^{2n}$. I was maily wondering about estimates in the intermediate case, but I guess the only one (at leat which I can easily see) is by using an integral estimate with $\nabla f$ (Taylor, basically). Which doesn't really help me with my problem, but that's it